# How Does the Isabella Hallucination Work?

Tags: the-sopranos

Throughout the episode (S01E12), Tony encounters a beautiful Italian woman whom he believes is his next door neighbor's maid while they are away. We later learn at the end of the episode, that the woman, Isabella, was a hallucination created by the combo of Lithium and Prozac that Tony is prescribed.

My question is this: How exactly does the Isabella hallucination work? Is Tony talking to himself while nobody is actually there similar to Tyler Durden in Fight Club? Tony takes Isabella out to lunch in an Italian restaurant. Is he simply sitting by himself talking to an empty chair? Does this hallucination work differently than this? I feel like I missed something.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40738127-the-sopranos-sessions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not expressly shown or stated, but it could either be one of two things;

Tony *believes* Isabella exists, and speaks and "interacts" with no one, but "sees" Isabella.

Or

Tony is sitting in a chair somewhere and the entire interaction takes place in his mind.  More like a daydream.

Again, which one is actually happening isn't entirely clear.